# How to protect contact forms against being misused for mass-mailing?

Tags: appsec, spam, attack-vector

A common function of contact forms is to send the contact message not only to the site owner but also to the person who sent the contact request. What are good measures to protect against the form being used as a spamming tool by an automated script that submits it millions of times with different email addresses?

I can think of several approaches, but each one also has a downside or is not very effective.

- CAPTCHAs can be broken too easily nowadays and are a hassle for the human submitter.
- Rate limiting (only n submits per IP per day) won't help against a distributed script and may hinder proxied users.
- Spam detection may generate false positives and if it's resource-intensive will make the site susceptible to DDOS attacks.

Each measure makes it harder/more resource intensive for an attacker though so he might just look elsewhere. How prevalent is comment-form spam? Do I have to worry about it?

Comment: reCaptcha still do a very good job these days. No thing more easy to go through for a real user than that check box.

Answer (score 8):

You're right that allowing arbitrary, unauthenticated internet users to control both the content and the recipient of email messages sent by your web service (i.e. your website's "contact us" form) is a bad idea, and a potentially attractive target for spammers.

If it is important to you to:

- enable the user to specify a recipient for the message; and
- send a message to that recipient upon submission of the form,

then I suggest you at least prevent the user controlling the content of the message.

Why not take the sort of approach that [GNU Mailman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Mailman) takes when it receives a subscription request? That is, send a confirmation email first, along the lines:

> You, or somebody pretending to be you, submitted a message to use
>   using the contact form on our website. This came from [IP ADDRESS] and
>   gave your email as the sender's email address. If you made this
>   submission, please click [HERE], or reply to this email keeping the
>   subject line intact, to confirm your contact form submission, and we
>   will read your submission and reply in due course. If you did not send
>   us a message via our contact form, please ignore this message.

You could rate-limit this so that it permits no more than one anonymous submission to a given email address per (week|month|year|whatever), with the timer being reset if the user confirms as per the above instructions. That would discourage trolls from using the form to nuisance innocent people by causing them to be sent spurious confirmation messages.

In any case, only once the submitter of the contact form has been verified to have access to the email account submitted, should the contents of the message submitted be made visible to the user of that email account.

Comment: This has the drawback that any kind of structure that the form offered will be lost. E.g. you can't make your users enter certain "mandatory fields" or the like.

Comment: @fgysin, I disagree. Essentially what I was proposing is that a submitted form should go into a quarantine queue. If the user follows the confirmation instructions within a defined time period (say 48h), then the submitted form is forwarded to the site owner (and, perhaps, to the email address given by the submitter). If the user does not follow the confirmation instructions within that time period, then the submitted form is deleted from the queue. None of that prevents the submitted form from its retaining structure or mandatory fields.

Comment: @sampablokuper: Ah right, I misunderstood that. In that case I have no objections. :)

Answer (score 2):

Allow me a partial answer based on previous experience in systems administration: Yes, it is reasonably prevalent, and you have to worry about it.

As politically incorrect as it might sound: Check if you can geographically define your user base (where are the people you wish to do business with?), and rate limit everyone else via GeoIP lookups.

Comment: Great thought and may solve many use cases for local businesses and such. But there is still a better solution to be found.

Answer (score 1):

AKISMET is an interesting alternative. Is like a spam filter, but outsourced and  that combines the knowledge it accumulates from many sites to better protect yours from SPAM.

While it is mostly used to protect wordpress comments (I´ve used it and I really dont remember asingle false positive or spam passing the filter), its API could be used for any other thing: https://akismet.com/development/

You submit the contact data detail to their API and they will give you a positive or negative answer for it. There are APIs for reporting false positives and false negatives.

There are some privacy concers, of course, to be considered here, since they will receive your contact data. However, is an option that could be considered.

Another suggestion is to use it in combination with the ones that you already mentioned: If there are too many contacts from the same IP, submit the contact for akismet for checking.

Comment: I don't think this answer relates really to the question.

Comment: AKISMET can be used for contact forms, even it is more broadly used to comment boxes. How exactly is not related to the question?. I´ll fix the link to the API that could be used.

Comment: Then maybe you should more describe how the software can actually help instead of given some rough description (spam filter) and let the user dig through the website to find out how this is useful for contact forms.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution on improving the answer. Hope its more clear now.

Comment: Akismet seems aimed at filtering out spam content, that is not really what the OP is asking about. Do you know if Akismet can also filter out bad email return addresses?

Comment: I dont think the OP was only worried with bad return email addresses, but was with valid (but ilegitimate) ones that could end up receiving spam through the contact form: "A common function of contact forms is to send the contact message not only to the site owner *but also to the person who sent the contact request.*" That said, Its an interesting question and I´m not aware if do check for it too. What I can say is that you can send many data (including email) too, so it is used somehow, but not sure if that filters bad return emails.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Akismet could immediately flag contact form entries that appear to be spam and prevent them from being sent at all, until reviewed, or apply different rules to limit abuse. It's definitely an interesting idea.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded comment Cristian. When I said "bad" I meant an email address that was being used abusively. "so it is used somehow" doesn't really give me confidence that their service will meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: Well, if spammers start using my legitimate email for spam I would not like it to be blocked by akismet for that. It would need to check if the email is used ONLY for that or MOSTLY for that, then sure. But many spammers use legitimate forged address that they dont control (like mine or yours) and that looks like one of the scenarios the OP is worried about. The OP may make this clearer, but from the possible solutions he gave as example, none would cover this too, and akismet is definitivvely an option to the examples he gave without that drawbacks (but maybe others).

Comment: By the way, I would not like that any comment system sends me an email to proof I own the email on every comment I post. For me anything that puts effort on the legitimate user to fight ilegitimate users (like captcha) is going in the wrong direction :)

Comment: @NeilSmithline - The use of AKISMET suggested in this answer has really nothing to do with email addresses. A spammer will specify a (theoretically) valid email addresses to receive the spam, and the "Spam" is in the "Message" field of the contact form. Whether a contact form submission is potentially "Spam" cannot be determined by the destination email address, which really belongs to an innocent person that will receive the spam message. Here, AKISMET is used to examine the content of the message associated with the contact form submission to try to determine if it is spam or not.

Comment: Thanks @KevinFegan. I agree. It seems I was confused about the exact question that was being asked.